# Force refresh of audio devices on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio

Whenever I turn off my TV, it [disappears from my audio output on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLh7E.png), and when I turn the TV back on it remains gone.

I can make it come back by right clicking on the speaker icon and running "Troubleshoot sound problems" (cancelling the troubleshooter as soon as it opens).

I was wondering if there was any way to do this via command-line so I can put it into some script? Alternatively, is there a way to not having it disappear at all, or reappear automatically when the TV is turned on?

Comment: You can try to restart Audio Endpoint Builder:

    net stop audioendpointbuilder
    net start audioendpointbuilder

Or Audio Service too:

    net stop audiosrv
    net stop audioendpointbuilder
    net start audioendpointbuilder
    net start audiosrv

But if HDMI device is not recognized at low-level (Kernel Streaming), this won't help.